# Unable to install uplift package, after updating to R 4.2.1

Tags: r

Might be a silly question since I am very new to R.
I kept having an error every time attempting to install uplift packages in R. Moreover, I just updated R to the newest version 4.2.1. Is that related to the error?Please help

This is the error message in R:

```
> install.packages("uplift")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/marco/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘uplift’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
> library(uplift)
Error in library(uplift) : there is no package called ‘uplift’
```

I've tried to reinstall the whole R and R studio, and it kept failing.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer. It turns out that the package was archived, and it can be performed/pulled out using this code:

```
library(remotes)

install_version("uplift","0.3.5") #Pulling out the latest package

library(uplift)
```